# Laravel public directory listing Redirect Loop Error - need to fail gracefully

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

II'm using Laravel and have a folder of uploaded files in my public directory called `uploads`.

I want to make sure that no one can accidentally navigate to the root of that directory, so I've added a route as follows:

```
Route::get('uploads', function(){
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

This isn't working as I'm getting a redirect loop error in my browsers. I've narrowed this down to being the fact that the directory exists - if I remove / rename the directory, the route works as expected.

That makes me think there's a better way to handle this. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: None can access that directory and you don't need to declare a route for that.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha that's great, but how do i deal w/ the redirect loop? I at least need that to fail a bit more gracefully...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the redirect loop seems to come from **trailing slash redirection**, defined in Laravel default .htaccess file. Removing following line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

will fix the problem with redirect loop on folders residing in public folder.
This however takes you one step back, because now you do not have trailing slash redirection.
Insted what you can do is redirect trailing slashes only **if not an existing directory**, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Second thing you probably want to do is remove the same condition from the last block of Laravel default .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This block is saying: "Redirect everything to index.php file, except existing files and folders." I commented out the directory condition, because I do not want people to access folder index in my public folder. If you do, uncomment it.
 This is my complete .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect trailing slashes
    # Only if not existing directory. This prevents redirect loop.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect everything to index.php if not existing file like css or jpg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a whirl later on and let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in assuming that this directory may be accessible. If you've checked and it's not, you may want to follow this step just in case you decide to switch to a host that does not have it hidden by default.

Just add this to your .htaccess

```
    Options -Indexes
```

Comment: i've added the .htaccess file already. the problem is with Laravel and a redirect loop now. (see comments on the question)